# How to fix access denied on create or edit *.aspx files?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2013 (logged in with my account). Permissions i have is `Full Control, Design, Edit, Contribute, Read, Limited Access, Create new subsites, View Only, Approve, Manage Hierarchy, Restricted Read, Restricted Interfaces for Translation`. I'm able to successfully create and save `*.html` pages, but getting 'Server error: access denied.' on save or create `*.aspx` pages. How do i fix this?

[image: Check Permissions]

Comment: where are you trying to create the page? Are you able to create pages by going into the library?

Comment: @TaranGoel i'm able to create (and edit) a page from office online in a browser, but i can't do the same from sharepoint designer.

Comment: Can you do "Check Permissions" from site settings and post the results?

Comment: @TaranGoel screenshot uploaded

Comment: because you have the deny option, resolution3 will work for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be multiple source of this issue:

1. Master page or the Page Layout used are checked out or are in pending state

   - Resolution : Check in & Publish the master page
2. User don't have permission to Master Page Gallery

   - Resolution : Give user Read access to the Master Page Gallery
3. Running custom Scripts on sites is disabled##

   - Resolution: Enable it. Please see the article [here](http://sharepointaaron.com/1/post/2014/12/sharepoint-designer-online-server-error-access-denied.html).

Comment: Where can i find master page in a SharePoint online?

Comment: ~SiteCollectionURL/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: though 3rd will work for you. Please see the suggested answer here - https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/297285

Comment: still have same error and 'Add and Customize Pages' still 'Deny' in check permission.
Should i wait up to 24 hours now?

Comment: I am assuming you did the 3rd option. These settings take time to get updated, so you can in the meanwhile make sure 1 & 2 are OK. Let us know the results. Most of the time its faster then 24hrs..:)

Comment: How do i Check in & Publish the master page and give users access? Is there anywhere some tutorial about that (i am complete newbie, sorry)?

Comment: I guess you never checked out the master page and never removed the permissions. If thats the case option3 will work though you can make sure of it. Please goto master page gallery and see if there's a green arrown associated with the master page(Sign of check out).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/0Mz3wc8.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25585/discussion-between-taran-goel-and-user3239600).

Comment: i'm in chat.

_(15 chars)_

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused when there is Degradation of the SharePoint Online Service. Microsoft put the site into Read me Only mode which can cause this error as i have just experienced.